# Batch rename file names, retain ext?

Tags: batch-file, rename, filenames, recursive

(Win10) In a batch file, how do I recursively rename files*names* in a folder? **Not the extension**.

e.g.

Files to rename: heavy.doc, bright.jpg, fast.docx, quiet.png, etc

Rename to: A1.*, A2.*, A3.*, A4.*, etc (where the .* retains the original ext)

Becomes: A1.doc, A2.jpg, A3.docx, A4.png, etc

Thanks!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271586/rename-multiple-files-in-cmd) useful question and [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/) how-to. Do you need to do this as part of a script? Why not use a standalone renaming program?

Comment: The first appends a set string to a filename. Interesting, but not what I was after. The second does the job nicely, albeit with brackets. As for needing to do it in a batch-script, it would be nice to have a one-click solution that I can use regularly, and I love learning new ways to use such scripts. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at the reference page for [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), I could come up with this:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set a=1
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%G in ('dir /b /s /A:-D') do (
    ren "%%G.%%H" "A!a!.%%H" 
    set /a a+=1
)
```

**Update:** it would be better to pass the initial folder as a parameter, so that the script itself can be placed anywhere and does not risk getting renamed itself.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set a=1
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%G in ('dir /b /s /A:-D %1') do (
    ren "%%G.%%H" "A!a!.%%H" 
    set /a a+=1
)
```

**Explanation:**

`@echo off` this avoids every command to be written to the console.

`setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` this is needed in order for the `a` variable to actually increase.

`set a=1` we create a counter variable called `a` and set its initial value to `1`.

`for /f` loop against a list of filenames.

`tokens=1,2 delims=.` the filename is going to be split when a `.` is encountered. We are interested in the first two tokens resulting from this operation. **Note:** it is expected that filenames do *not* contain a dot, except between the basename and the extension.

`%%G` is the name of the first token (it's implicit that the second is going to be `%%H`).

`in ('dir /b /s /A:-D %1')` loop over the results of the `dir` command, that lists the files in the directory passed as a parameter `%1` with the following options: `/b` clean output, `/s` include results from subdirectories, `/A:-D` only list files and not folder names.

`ren "%%G.%%H" "A!a!.%%H"` rename the filename (`%%G.%%H` reconstructs the original filename) to a constant `A` plus the variable `a`'s current value, plus the original extension `%%H`.

`set /a a+=1` increments the counter variable.

Comment: Great script, simlev.. Thanks muchly.. will play with it!